# Excel - How do I count instances of by counting the assigned value for each cell entry?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Okay, I know that the title of my question is terrible, but I'm rather new to Excel and I frankly don't even know if what I want to accomplish is possible.

So I want to create an Excel spreadsheet to record what cards I get from card packs for a game I play. Each of the cards have a rarity value of common, rare, epic, and legendary. So I want to set up my spread sheet so that I choose the name of the card from a drop down list (This is easy enough). Then, I want to tally up how many cards of a certain rarity I got.

So I have a table of every card name and their corresponding rarity. What I planned on doing was to have a COUNTIF function where the criteria is a VLOOKUP function that looks up the name of the card, then returns the rarity value and checks if its common, rare, epic, or legendary.

I planned on having four cells, each tallying how many common/rare/epic/legendary cards I got. But for some reason, it always returns 0. I think it has to do with the fact that VLOOKUP can't be used to look up a list of values and can only take in one search term at a time. But again, I don't know if what I'm trying to do is even possible.

Any and all help would be very appreciated.

Edit: I added a picture to show roughly what I wish to accomplish.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have kept the solution simple. Just added a row B to calculate card type. I have used this formula..

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$E$2:$F$7,2,FALSE)
```

Then for Common count I have used formula

```
=COUNTIF(B$2:B$8,"Common")
```

for Rare cards I have use this formula

```
=COUNTIF(B$2:B$8,"Rare")
```

... and so on.

If you do not want newly added column to visible, you can hide it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! I didn't know that you could just hide columns! That is indeed the simplest solution. But just in case, is there by any chance some way to do this without that extra column?

Comment: That would be difficult. But the additional column can be not just B, but Z or anything which will not even come on the screen